# how to implement queueing in Application server?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, websphere, weblogic, geronimo

I am using `Apache Geronimo` Application server, I want to customize queuing in Geronimo like, All the requests are stored in Application server queue and it release one by one.
That means, Application server serves only one request at a time. once previous one is completed next request will be release. I want to set like this.

I hope, you understand what I am trying. If anyone have any queries let me know.

If anyone work on this concept,suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the database thread pool size to 1(id it let's you), and also make Servlets as single thread, but there is no warranty about the queue, maybe the second one in a queue goes before first, and why do you need to do it so?

another way is that every requests are filtered by a servlet filter that that filter lock a synchronized object from beginning till end response, this ensures you no any other thread would take the lock and do the same (at least for http requests)

servlet single thread mode:

```
public class AloneServlet extends HttpServlet implements SingleThreadModel {
//....
}

the servlet filter approach
public final class HitCounterFilter implements Filter {
   private Object lock=new Object();
   //...
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      synchronized(lock){
      chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);
      }
   }
}
```

the two samples above are for http requests, you need to do same for web-services, or etc.

please tell why do you want your server goes single thread, maybe there are more better approach available, I never suggest these approaches :)

**Approach 2:**
first code the filter code

```
package com.stackoverflow.supportbuddy
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

// Implements Filter class
@ServletFilter(urlPatterns={"/pages/myJSP.jsp"})// for Java EE 6+
public class SyncFilter implements Filter  {
   public void  init(FilterConfig config)throws ServletException{}
   @Override
   private static Object lock=new Lock();
   @Override
   public void  doFilter(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain)throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {
      //each thread needs to lock the "lock" object and this ensures you only one thread will be forwarded.
      synchronized(lock){
      chain.doFilter(request,response);
      }
   }
   @Override
   public void destroy( ){}
}
```

then map the filter to desired jsp file, for example if `jsp` file is located under `/pages` folder, then you need to map the filter as this in `web.xml` or using annotation in newer version of Java EE

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
.....
    <filter>
       <filter-name>SycnFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>com.stackoverflow.supportbuddy.SyncFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>SycnFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/pages/myJSP.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
.....
</web-app>
```

finally have a try :)

Comment: we developed one Application using `Wolfram Mathematica`. Using this Technology we can handle heavy computations less than 1 sec. Actually end-users are not interacts with this Application. The application what it does, It fetching data from `DB1` and computation will be happen and stored in `DB2`. End-users are interacts with `DB2`.for this interaction we are developed another applications using `Node.js, Javascript`. With one Mathematica licence we will get only one kernel.so at a time two Application's can't run. because of this we want to customize queuing in Application server.

Comment: so does each `DB1` to `DB2` data transfer effect to another one? IF not there is no need for forcing AS go single thread. and if there is just one system interact with `DB1` so why do you want to implement it as JEE application? can't switch the `WM` to JSE? another way is setting `DB1` connection pool to 1

Comment: Hmm, how do you run the `WM` application? is it exe file? or JEE module?

Comment: `WM` provide some tags. using these tags we can write the `WM` code in `JSP` page.finally my entire application code in `JSP`.

Comment: so I think the servlet filter approach(2nd. approach) would help you, have a try. :)

Comment: I am new to Application server side, even I don't know which concept will be useful for me. According to your suggestion I will try `Servlet filter approach`. for this am I need to write any java program or it's a separate component. can you suggest me.

Comment: I updated the answer buddy, check the *approach2* section, have a try and have some feedback :), hope this help you out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33550/discussion-between-ur-truly-friend-and-user-2511414)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the first time to understanding JAVA code. so I will check it once I understand let you inform .